# jquery ui dialog not cropping sprite properly?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, sprite

I'm working with jquery ui dialog, and am running into an odd image sprite problem on the close "x" buttons on all my dialogs.  It looks like the image is not being cropped properly:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLUrH.png

I've re-downloaded the ui dialog package, but that didn't help.  I've checked the code on my site against others using ui dialog successfully (via firebug), and cannot spot any obvious discrepancies.  I've also scoured the internet for possible causes of this problem, but it seems that no one has ever run into this problem in the history of the world.  The search results were really that barren.

Any advice on where I should look for potential causes of this problem would be greatly appreciated.  I've reached a debugging mindblock and am not sure what to check next.  (My jquery-fu is not strong, so perhaps there are some obvious/simple checks I am overlooking?)

Comment: Might be some CSS conflict between jQueryUI and your own CSS or any other CSS code you're including. Can you post an example?

Comment: My guess is that you have a conflicting CSS rule somewhere that is overwriting the `width` and `height` of that .ui-icon span.

Comment: I also wondered if it might be a CSS thing, but my CSS file is pretty bare-bones, and I didn't think anything in the downloaded CSS file would be a problem (I used the ThemeRoller).  But I just checked again, and I found the problematic line in the CSS that was provided along with the download, though:

`.ui-icon-closethick {padding:3em;}`

I'm not sure why that was included in the package, but commenting it out indeed takes care of the problem.  Thanks for the help, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Rogue CSS line of mysterious origin, now commented out, and problem fixed.